# How can I ignore zero-values in an Excel graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have built a template in Excel that organizes data and shows a graph. The graph plots two fields, Var1 and Var2, on the vertical against year along the horizon. Both Var1 and Var2 are pulled from cells that are formulae.

I have found that I cannot tell the graph to ignore certain years from one variable and not from another. I have also found that the graph of either variable will show show values of zero. I would like for it to not. The only way I have found around this is to go to the cells from which the graph pulls and delete the formulae therein. This is a tedious process as we use this template for many instances. Is there a way to tell Excel to ignore cells that have a zero value even if it is the output of a function?[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant, clear well worded question. +1

Comment: What is actually in the cells displaying as zero (number `0`, blank cell, formula that returns a null (""), something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are various methods for avoiding the zeroes, none of them are perfect.
Below are a couple of such methods.

**Filtering the data set**

1. Select the data range.
2. On the *Data* tab, click *Filter* in the *Sort & Filter* group,
   to add a filter to all of the columns.
3. Click the drop-down arrow on the column's first row and uncheck `0`.
4. Click *OK* to filter the column, which will filter the entire row.
   Be sure to remove the filter when you're done.

**Replace 0s with NA()**

1. Select the data set
2. Click *Find & Select* in the *Editing* group on the *Home* tab and choose Replace,
   or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Enter `0` in *Find what*.
4. Enter `=NA()` in *Replace*
5. Click Options to display additional settings and
   check *Match entire cell contents*.
6. Click *Replace All*.
7. Click *Close* and *OK*.

For more information see the article
[How to suppress 0 values in an Excel chart](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-suppress-0-values-in-an-excel-chart/).

Answer (score 0):

With updated Excel, I believe you could do this via "Select Data" of your excel chart, then follow the screenshot [image: screenshot of Excel-dialogue]